# SIP load balancing

Tags: voip

Folks, we own a set of phone numbers which we have routed to our VOIP provider.  In turn, they forward the calls to our Asterisk box coloed in their datacenter.

Is there any possible way to get another VOIP provider, and use them for either fault tolerance, or to load balancing incoming calls to our numbers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: Yes.

Longer Answer: Yes, how much money do you want to spend and what precisely is the problem you want to solve?

There are a number of fault tolerant (high availability), failover, and load-balancing options you can implement. But it's nearly impossible to provide any specific guidance because it will depend on your architecture, needs, and budget.

For example, generally and generically speaking, you could do a polling system with redundant Asterisk machines. Or you could do a round-robin service implementation. Or you could use content delivery devices doing load balancing on incoming connections.

There are numerous hardware and software fault tolerance, failover, and balancing solutions. Obviously your architecture is the primary factor. But other factors (What form of network management do you use? Is your VoIP provide full-service?) play a role in any recommendation too.

Comment: Excellent!  So round robin scenario... Can I have calls to 1-232-222-3333 be RRed between 2 voip providers?